# "I want you succeed in life"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

> **I want you succeed in life.**

Is the above sentence correct? It sounds grammatical if we think of the sentence as '*I want that you succeed in life*' and take 'that you succeed in life' as the object of the verb.

Is it the same as:

> **I want you to succeed in life**.

Will it be correct to think as it? Is the particle 'to' omitted in the sentence?

(I don't mean that I want to succeed).

Answer (score 1):

The correct form would be: "**I want you to succeed in life**." The word **to** is used to connect your wishes to the specific person, in this case **you**. The phrases like **"I want you to"**, **"I need you to"** are always used with a **to**. Honestly it also sounds better to the ear.

Comment: Is the sentence ' I want you succeed in life' correct and if it is correct what does it mean?

Comment: 'I want you to succeed in life ' has another meaning that I want you in order to succeed in life. I'm totally confused .

Comment: No, we don't use it in the form " I want you succeed in life". We use always use it with a "to" if  you are expressing your wishes for him/her. If you mean you need him/her for your own success, you can use "in order to" instead of "to": "I want you in order to succeed in life.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is incorrect. The sentence should be in **“verb + to-infinitive”**  form. Therefore, **“I want you to succeed in life”** is correct.

If you mean that you want the person to maintain the state of success, then you can say **“I want you succeeding”**.